# Determine if tap is within circular area

Tags: geometry, touch, area, touchscreen, ontouch

In my app I am currently able to work out whether the user's tap is within a rectangular area simply by checking all of the following conditions are true:

- Finger **X** > rectangle **X**
- Finger **Y** > rectangle **Y**
- Finger **X** < rectangle **X** + rectangle **Width**
- Finger **Y** < rectangle **Y** + rectangle **Height**

However, I now have to determine if the user taps within a *circular* area.  Currently I have a circular shape on screen and have resorted to just checking it's bounding rectangle, which works but obviously isn't great.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [distance between two points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance#Geometry) in two dimensions is defined as

```
 dist = sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2)
```

To check if your tap point is inside a circle, take the centre of your circle as (x1,y1), and the 'tap location' as (x2,y2), and check if

```
sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2) < R
```

With R being the radius of your circle.

**Edit:**

As John mentioned, from a computational point of view it is more interesting to compare vs R^2, to avoid the sqrt for every tap. So the condition becomes:

```
(x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2 < R^2
```

Comment: Yes, but it is cheaper to square `R` than to compute a square root, so it is usually better to perform the test `(x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2) < R^2`.